# Discord.js message is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const testBot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


testBot.on("message", (message) => {

    if(command === 'help') {
        message.channel.send('ok');
      } else
      if (command === 'hey') {
        message.channel.send('yes?');
      }

});

testBot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
})


testBot.login("Secret");
```

I'm a node.js beginner.

the error is this.
'ReferenceError: message is not defined'  How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your variable message is not declared yet

Can you try with something like this ?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const testBot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

testBot.on("message", (message) => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(command === 'help') {
        message.channel.send('ok');
      } else
      if (command === 'hey') {
        message.channel.send('yes?');
      }
});

testBot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
})


testBot.login("Secret");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you should put

```
testBot.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.client) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Good answer but also try to include why it works; in this case, because of the scope of `message`.